# Meaning of "Would you value the ethics of consequence over means?"

Tags: meaning, british-english, sentence

I've been reading a book for a while and I've stumbled on the following sentence, which I didn't quite understand:

> Would you value the ethics of consequence over means?

The context is the following:
Person A steals a valuable book and doesn't tell his superiors (In the book, this is punishable by death, since he's hiding information and this act caused a war earlier), person B is As friend and doesn't do anything about the book (person B is religious).

The mentioned superiors find out about the book and thus, person A is sent to court, where person B is a witness.

Person A asks B to lie, but him being religious, isn't able to do so.

Since B didn't lie in court, but did nothing before the act of hiding the information was found out (aka "I'm all good with it until there isn't something for me to lose), is called a hypocrite by person A, so he goes through a psychological drama, before talking to person C (person C being a priest and a good friend of person B).

During the discussion, person B lets C in on his drama and gives the aforementioned question as answer to his person Bs psychological drama.

Comment: @Kris Didn't you mean 'the ends justify the means'? In any event this is more a question of philosophy (ethics) than of English language.

Comment: So you say it means: "The fact that he went to court is enough, it doesn't matter how he got there" (aka: C being against A)?

Comment: Some argue that ends justify the means. That should set you on the track to understand the author's point of view and his implication in the sentence. Interpreting whole sentences/ ideas, or drawing implications amounts to literary interpretation and so, is off topic on ELU. I'm afraid you have to draw your own conclusions.

Comment: @WS2 The point has been lost -- I meant that as a play on words. And yes, I had already close voted the post.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about philiosophy.

Answer (score 1):

An *ethics of consequence* is one which posits that the ethical value of an action is dependent upon its outcome, or perhaps its foreseeable outcome (different ethics of consequence could disagree on how much one is culpable for an unforeseeable outcome, and questions around the difference between two or more foreseeable outcomes with different likelihoods).

An *ethics of means* is one which puts forward certain rules, and holds that the ethical stance is to follow them.

In practice, there are definite overlaps. One is that ethics of means often arise out of considering possible outcomes in the abstract (e.g. we could argue that the ethics of means that considers it unethical to ever drink and drive is in fact an ethics of consequence because the rule against drinking and driving is there to prevent accidents) so the difference may be primarily about when one does or doesn't decide to make exceptions to rules. An ethics of means can also include consideration of outcome, e.g. many concepts of a *Just War* are primarily ethics of means but also consider a war for which a victorious outcome cannot be reasonable foreseen as unethical as it can only lead to bloodshed without any benefit (some make a further *of means* exception for defence against invaders of ones homeland as always justifiable).

The character in your story is including the argument in favour of one or the other of these, as part of his moral wrestling over the actions he did and didn't take.